# Sell Stock using Limit

Tags: stocks

I'm starting out as a small time investor and had some fun buying 10 shares of a stock at $14.50 per share. Right now, the stock is at 16$ (up from it's $13.20 low that I bit to early on).

The stock has moved up to $22.00 in the past and I am looking to sell at this point again. My question is that if I put a limit sell at $22.00 now, will it not sell until it's at $22.00 and I will continue to keep the stock?

I just don't want to hit the confirm button to early without knowing.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you'll still be owning stock if you simply place an order. Shares will only be exchanged for cash when someone matches your offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I put a limit sell at $22.00 now, will it not sell until it's at $22.00 and I will continue to keep the stock?

Basically yes. But note that brokers generally don't allow such limit orders to persist indefinitely. The default may even be that they're only valid until the end of the day, and usually the maximum validity is 30 or 60 days.

Comment: The website says 6months and the "checkout" says it's good till 8/15.

But that's what I thought. Thanks!

Comment: Fidelity lets me place "good 'til canceled" orders that can last up to 6 months.

Comment: After looking further, my site does the same. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is partly wrong. My broker allows for good till cancelled to be openned for 12 months, but what you also need to be aware of is that the exchange may not allow limit orders too far away from the current price. In this situation a far off order will be cancelled by your broker. You should check with your broker or exchange what the range is.